# Local Storage not stored after page refresh

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm having a really hard time understanding what I did wrong in my code in order to have a value saved in local storage.

I have a pretty big code project so I'll try to summarize what the program is tryin to do overall.
I am pulling news articles from the news API and displaying the articles; each article (depending on the publication it came from) pushes a different numeric value into an array `allSource2`.
I then take the sum of this array to arrive to a "score" (variable is called `sum`)

I basically want that score to be locally stored, so that it is available even after a page refresh.
I think something wrong might be happening because of where I put the `localStorage` function. Currently I put it under the click event that also pushes the numeric value in the array (when you click the article title).
I am super confused at where else it could be, so that it truly updates the `sum` every time that sum changes.

Also, it does work to store it (I checked `localStorage` on the console, after a refresh it still works, but after refreshing and then clicking on another article, it resets to whatever the value of this article is)

I didn't put the entire code, as it's insanely long. everything else is working fine, it's just that.
Also, the all of this is contained within one big function

I define `let sum =0;` at the beginning of the code.
Then, this is the click event.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('article-rating')[i]
  .addEventListener('click', function(event) {

    sum = allSource2.reduce((tempSum, val) => tempSum + val);
    console.log("article score is now" + " " + sum);
    var lastname = localStorage.getItem("overallsum");
    localStorage.setItem("overallsum", sum);


 });
```

I also tried to put the `var lastname = localStorage.getItem("overallsum");` at the beginning of the code, when the first function but no luck.

Thanks a lot for your help!
and apologies for any formatting issues, I'm super new to this.

Comment: Keep in mind that localStorage is a global object, so if you have more than one event listeners (that `i` index makes me thing you are looping) then only the last one will be persisted, overriding the previous ones. That is because you're using `overallsum` - maybe you want to generate different names for each event?

Comment: For sure when the click event gets trigger the value of `sum` is being stored in the local sotrage, that without a doubt. But I think the error might be somewhere else in the code. With this I mean that it's not enogugh with that snippet. As @Gonzalo said, there may be other `localStorage` API calls that are overriding the one in the code that you show us.

Comment: Thanks guys, let me actually edit the answer to show you the full code; because I agree it's probably somewhere else and I've been looking for days and can't figure it out

Comment: @FranciscoHanna I updated the orignal question with the full code :)

Answer (score 0):

Each time you click the event the `overallsum` is getting set and that is the problem. If the `overallsum` is a one time store to the local storage then you can check if the value of `overallsum` is `null`, and if so store the value for the first time.

Example:

```js
if (localStorage.getItem("overallsum") === null) {
  localStorage.setItem("overallsum", sum);
}
```

Otherwise, if the `overallsum` is something, then for every individual article you could 2D array and then set the value with the same conditional check.